# Rodar javascript após troca de página

Tags: javascript, runtime

Bom dia. Desenvolvi um script para ser executado em uma determinada página da web, uma automação de ações.

```
[...]
if (codigo == codigo1) {
    processar(codigo2);
  } else {
    if (quantAldeias > 0) {
      $('.groupRight').click();
      var nextRun = confirm("Fazer?");
        if (nextRun == true) {
            processar(codigo1);
            quantAldeias--;
        };
     }
}
[...]
```

Minha intenção é que ele executasse **$('.groupRight').click();**, que dispara a troca da página atual por outra, e após aberta a próxima página, executar o resto do bloco. O que acontece é que todo o código é acionado, e nada acontece na próxima página.

Tentei usar:

```
setTimeout(function(){
         $(document).ready(function() {
         quantAldeias--;
         processar(codigo1);
       });
       }, 3000);
```

e window.onload, mas não funcionaram. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Madson, eu não entendi. Você faz um reload na página inteira? Pois se for assim o teu script não terá escopo na nova página. O que você quer só funcionaria com ajax.

Comment: meu script muda a página atual. Então com js, quando eu mudo a página, é impossível manter um script em execução rodando? Pois eu o disparo através do scratchPad do Mozila

Comment: Quando você troca a página inteira o javascript anterior e todos os objetos da página anterior são descartados. Experimenta fazer um script com o greasemonkey, pode funcionar.

Comment: Ah entendi, muito obrigado :)